# how to show new screen using GI in mobile app

Tags: acumatica, acumatica-kb

What I want to show is the "Services Rendered" screen in the mobile app, but showing the generic query GI000100, something like Purchase Order.

I enclose my site map code, can you tell me what I'm doing wrong or how to display the generic query correctly.

Thanks in advance.

```
** Code Update Menu
update sitemap {

  add folder "ServicesRendered" {
    type = HubFolder
    isDefaultFavorite = True
    displayName = "Services Rendered 1"
    icon = "system://Cart"
    add item "GI000100" {
      displayName = "Services Rendered 2"
      icon = "system://Cart"
    }
  }
  add item "XP302000" {
    displayName = "Services Rendered"
    icon = "system://Cart"
    visible = False
  }
  
}

***Generic Inquiry
```

[image]

```
*** Screen XP302000
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please note that Purchase Orders screen (PO3010PL) in Mobile is a GI screen with Filters. All those tabs on your screenshots are filters created for that GI, see below:[image]

There you can add as many filters as you need and these will be included in your mobile app automatically.
Unfortunately you cannot include another screen in those filters.

If what you are trying to do is to redirect from your GI to your custom screen after tapping (selecting) a record then please review this recording of the Acumatica Virtual Developer Conference's presentation where we go step by step on how to achieve that behavior:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N4UPVmP_RRQ

Comment: After watching the video and doing the tests, i worked as expected.
Thanks.